# Why can't I use JTAppleCalendar Pod File JTAppleCell in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, calendar, uicollectionview, jtapplecalendar

I am using a JTAppleCalendar pod file in my project and when I installed the pod file I couldn't use the method JTAppleCell and I just could use JTAppleDayCell I watched this video
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd_Gc67xzlw 
and this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOphH-h-qCs
 Here is my codes

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class calendarViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var calendarCollectionView: UICollectionView!


let formatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


}

extension calendarViewController : JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {


func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale


    let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")!
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 12 31")!

    let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
    return parameters
}


func calendar(_calebdar : JTAppleCalendarView , cellForItemAt date : Date , cellState : CellState , indexPath : IndexPath ) -> JTAppleDayCell {

    let cell = calendarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "JTCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! JTCustomCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text

    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only able to use `JTAppleDayCell` instead of `JTAppleCell`, then you are on the wrong version of the library. That video showed you for version 7.0

So the question I ask now is what version are you using?
put this in your podfile:

```
pod 'JTAppleCalendar'
```

Then go to your console and run `pod update`.

The version should say **7.0.4** (which is the latest version as of this date).
If it is saying some other version, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried to update that But I got this Error : tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Comment: in that case can you do a `pod --version` ? mine says 1.2.1 ; If you cocoapods itself is out of date then try updating cocoapods itself. If all else fails, then try putting this in your podfile and run a `pod install`.  Put this in pod file -> `pod 'JTAppleCalendar', :git => 'https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar.git', :branch => 'master'`